# Marklogic replacement character � to double quote

Tags: marklogic

How can I replace a character �  is a symbol found in the Unicode to double quote in Marklogic.  I found thousand of documents (xml format) that have the special character appears in random element nodes (some nodes have character � , some nodes don't). Want Searching a special character in documents and permanent replace double quote(").

```
let $doc := fn:doc("/user/24325.xml")//fields/SearchFieldvalue
let $b:=fn:replace($doc,"&#xfffd;","&quot;")
return ($doc,$b)

[1.0-ml] XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) 
fn:replace((fn:doc("/user/24325.xml")//fields/SearchField[1]/value,
fn:doc("/user/24325.xml")//fields/SavedSearchField[2]/value, 
fn:doc("/user/24325.xml")//fields/SavedSearchField[3]/value, ...), 
"&#xfffd;", "&quot;") -- arg1 is not of type xs:string?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I would handle the prevention side: you probably have these because documents were loaded with an incorrect encoding. One way to fix this is to reload the documents, but specifying the correct encoding.

I think you want to use `cts:highlight` to walk through the document and replace the offending characters:

```
cts:highlight(doc("/user/24325"), "&#xffffd;", '"')
```

The result will be the document with all matches of the replacement character replaced by a double quote.